# Hacer comparación de dos bases de datos con distinta colación

Tags: sql-server, sql, base-de-datos

Amigos buen día, estoy tratando de hacer una comparación entre dos bases de datos, una (`POS_EDIFAC`) con colación `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` y otra (`SantoDomingoPMS`) con `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Mi script es el siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.DETALLE DF 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SantoDomingoPMS.dbo.T_FACTURACLI
                 WHERE IDFactura = DF.FACTURA)
;
```

El problema es que obtengo el siguiente error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Sé que hay una forma de agregar un `COLLATE`, pero sinceramente no he encontrado la manera ideal de hacerlo. Agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchos *collate* entre los que SQL es incapaz de comparar de manera implícita, pero siempre puedes indicar el _collate al cual *convertir* la columna al vuelo y en el que quieres que se realice la comparación. Este *collate* puede ser el de alguna de las columnas o puede ser, incluso, un tercero.

Ejemplos, siguiendo la sentencia SQL de tu pregunta, serían:

```
//en este primer caso, convertimos el collate de SantoDomingoPMS.dbo.T_FACTURACLI
SELECT * 
  FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.DETALLE DF 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM SantoDomingoPMS.dbo.T_FACTURACLI A
                   WHERE A.IDFactura collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS = DF.FACTURA)
;

//en este segundo caso, convertimos el collate de POS_EDIFAC.dbo.DETALLE
SELECT * 
  FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.DETALLE DF 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM SantoDomingoPMS.dbo.T_FACTURACLI A
                   WHERE A.IDFactura = DF.FACTURA collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
;

//en este tercer caso, convertimos el collate de ambos
SELECT * 
  FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.DETALLE DF 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM SantoDomingoPMS.dbo.T_FACTURACLI A
                   WHERE A.IDFactura collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI = DF.FACTURA collate collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI)
```

Para finalizar, el *collate* NO necesariamente se define a nivel de base de datos. La base de datos, tiene una colación default, pero cada columna de algún tipo de datos de caracter (char, varchar) puede tener su propio collate.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya marqué tu respuesta como valida, me ayudó bastante.

Comment: Enhorabuena, @GioGómez, me alegra ser de ayuda. En StackOverflow, además de votar a favor de una respuesta, quién hizo originalmente la pregunta tiene la opción de marcarla como la respuesta aceptada. Esto es de beneficio para futuros visitantes, pues pueden ver con rapidez y claridad cuál fue la respuesta que te ayudó a resolver el problema. Para más información sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, te invito a hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres es obtener las facturas que no estén en la otra base de datos te recomiendo usar un `not in` que te traerá los registros que no estén en la subconsulta tu código quedaría así,

```
SELECT * FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.DETALLE DF 
WHERE DF.FACTURA NOT IN (SELECT IDFactura FROM SantoDomingoPMS.dbo.T_FACTURACLI);
```

Espero que te funciona.

Comment: El not in no me soluciona porque debo tener los ID que se están repitiendo y necesito poner este query para que se ejecute automaticamente. Esta es solo una consulta pero el script final será un DELETE FROM

Comment: pero que es lo que quieres formula bien tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: al script que puse arriba... necesito poder agregarle la colación con el comando COLLATE, pero no sé donde debe ir, en que parte del script

Comment: Pero primero indica que es lo que quieres y el resultado que esperas para poder ayudarte